Trouble finding the spectrum of a finite-dimensional linear operator

Consider $T:
\mathbb{C}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^4$ defined via $$   T:\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\right)=\left(0,
x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4, x_1-x_4, x_3\right) $$
Find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

This is  my attempt so far:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\lambda x_1=0 \\
\lambda x_2=x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4 \\
\lambda x_3=x_1-x_4 \\
\lambda x_4=x_3
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
If $\lambda = 0$, then from the last equation we get that $x_3 =0$. Therefore, from the third equation we get that $x_1 = x_4 $. Finally from the second eq. $x_2 = x_3$
That let us with a vector $(0, 0, 0, 0)$  so it is not eigenvector and therefore $0$ — not a eigenvalue $ \lambda = 0 \notin \sigma(T)$
When trying $\lambda \not = 0$ I have problems
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& x_4=\frac{x_3}{1} \\
& x_3=\frac{x_1-x_4}{\lambda}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then \begin{equation}
x_2=\frac{x_2}{\lambda}+\frac{x_4}{\lambda^2}-\frac{x_4}{\lambda}
\end{equation}
when solving  $x_2 \lambda^2+\left(x_4-x_2\right) \lambda-x_4=0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \lambda_1= 1 \\
& \lambda_2=- \frac{x_4}{x_2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I need some comment on what I have done and what to do when $\lambda =0$ since I am strugling with the eigenvalues

Your operator corresponds to the matrix
$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
                1 & 1 & -1 & -1\cr
                1 & 0 & 0 & -1\cr
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$
Do you know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix?  This is linear algebra...
